# mysql if no record

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this;

```
select value, date from table
where date in ('date1','date2','date3','date4','date5')
group by date
```

This gives results only if there is a record with given dates. But i want to get a row with "0" value even if there are no record with one of given dates. How can i do this?

```
5 | 02/04/2012
8 | 02/05/2012
3 | 02/06/2012
4 | 02/08/2012
```

>

```
5 | 02/04/2012
8 | 02/05/2012
3 | 02/06/2012
0 | 02/07/2012
4 | 02/08/2012
```

Comment: From where do you get this date 02/07/2012 for the row with 0 value

Comment: @AshReva That's what i am asking. Getting first results but need second results.

Comment: but can you tell me how should i bring this value 02/07/2012 if record is 0? will it be hard coded?

Comment: Also if possible can you post actual records

Comment: @AshReva If there is no record with that date it should still give that date with 0 value. Dates are last 5 days generated with php. I am getting total of value/day.

Comment: Actual query like : `SELECT date,listener,SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(time))) as total_time
FROM
(
    SELECT date,listener,time FROM db1
    where date in ( last 5 days)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT datelistener,time FROM db2
    where date in ( last 5 days)
) A GROUP BY date`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a date table, or create a temp table with dates. However, a date table will be your best option because it's small size and efficiency.

You're also incorrectly using `GROUP BY`. Please read [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html).